# bypass facebook recaptcha in selenium with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to bypass facebook captcha verification automaticaly. How can i do this?i wrote a bot and manage to solve the captcha. And remove the textarea attribute `style= display:'none'` to `'block'` and i can paste it in textarea but 'submit' button not clickable. How can I convert the button enable? especially with selenium.
Is there anybody to help me?

[image: this button is not clickable]

Comment: does it appear when you try to login?

Comment: yeah. I have to click the bottom of button but i cant

Comment: I mean, capchas are done specifically to avoid the use of bots or scripts to use company's features. I don't think there's a way to solve them without the use of advanced Computer Vision solutions

Comment: thks. but i really have to solve this problem in my project.

Comment: You have two options: (1) load in selenium an user profile where you are already logged in, this way when you run `driver.get('http://facebook.com/')` you will be automatically logged in. (2) use 2captcha to solve the captcha. I think the easiest way is (1) if you need help about it let me know

Comment: What problems did you have when using an user profile?

Comment: Hi i need a hand.
i can take reCaptcha v2 token. But my new promlem is :)) on submitting. How can enable submit button which is disable. My project work like this.

Comment: I am sending my request to 2Captcha and its server reply with token and i put token in textarea which i made style.display= 'inline'. At this point i have to submit but the button is not enable. So i used callback. It works, i mean button became enable but when i click it doesnt submit the form or textarea which i put myCaptchaToken. So that i cant progress on my project. Pls how can i pass this obstacle.

If anbody help me i will be appriciate
pls contact me to : ozknozn33@gmail.com